# PHP dynamic object properties syntax - is there a way to write this within one statement?

Tags: php, syntax, short

In PHP the following syntax is possible (access dynamic object property):

```
foreach($props as $prop) {
    echo $my_object->$my_property;
}
```

Also this is possible therefore:

```
foreach($obj as $o) {
    $prop = $o->key;
    echo $my_object->$prop;
}
```

The question is - can I write the above code within one line? I tried:

```
$my_object->$o->key;
$my_object->($o->key);
```

Both gives me an error. Can i write this within one statemen somehow?

Comment: `$my_object->{$o->key};` Curly syntax

Comment: Should the first example be `->$prop`?

Comment: Complex (curly) syntax: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing.complex

Comment: @Barmar I think we can almost certainly assume that out of the context, that it is only a typo, otherwise it wouldn't make much sense.